# Validation in wpf content control without using binding.validationRule

Tags: .net, wpf-controls

I have a content control whose instances are build dynamically on the fly with user interaction. the contents of this control vary depending on user choice. I want to validate these control. How will i define a validationrule without binding? please can someone suggest some approaches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/58dac1b0-ff83-48d7-90fd-7234ea6768d2), data validation is dependent on binding, however, as noted in the same post, there are workarounds.  One such workaround is to bind the property you wish to validate to a dummy variable.  If using a textbox you could bind it to the `tag` property of the textbox like this:

```
<TextBox>
 <TextBox.Text>
 <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag" Mode="OneWayToSource" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
  <Binding.ValidationRules>
   <local:NumericValidationRule />
  </Binding.ValidationRules>
 </Binding>
 </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Where `local:NumericValidationRule` is defined elsewhere.  If you can't create your controls using xaml you can still get the same effect using code.